# Alamofire Upload get returned JSON

Tags: swift, reflection, alamofire

question on getting at the result data in an Alamofire.upload call.

I am sending multipart form data to a server using the following code:

```
   sessionManager.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                if let name = currentPlace.name,
                    let data = name.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "placename", mimeType: "text/plain")
                }
                if let lat = currentPlace.location?.coordinate.latitude {
                    multipartFormData.append(String(describing: lat).data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "latitude", mimeType: "text/plain")
                }
                if let lon = currentPlace.location?.coordinate.longitude {
                    multipartFormData.append(String(describing: lon).data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "longitude", mimeType: "text/plain")
                }

                multipartFormData.append((User.current.scanMode.rawValue).data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "state", mimeType: "text/plain")
        },
            to: (url?.absoluteString)!,  headers: headers,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):


                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                        print(response.request)  // original URL request
                        print(response.response) // URL response
                        print(response.data)     // server data
                        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                        if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSArray {
                            for element in JSON {
                                print(element)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
        })
```

My challenge is to get the value of response.result.value in a form that I can validate.  The current debug output is:

```
(lldb) po response.result.value
▿ Optional<Any>
  ▿ some : 4 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : code
      - value : 200
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : id
      - value : 78230c53954a3adbf14b49cda127bf55
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : message
      - value : Successfully updated OID to DISTRIBUTED.
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - key : state
      - value : DISTRIBUTED
```

Looks like a array, but can't seem to get this casted or reflected into something I can use.  Usually I would use EVOReflection to get at this data as in:

```
 sessionManager.request((url?.absoluteString)!, method: .get, parameters: postParameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
            .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<AssetStateResponse>) in
                if let response = response.result.value {
                    completionHandler(response)
                } else {
                    // LATER: Better error handling
                }
        }
```

Any help appreciated, have been looking at this for a few days now, missing something simple I suspect.

Comment: `response.result.value.class` gives what? Seems like a dict.

Comment: you can call `validate()` on your Request. Method returns `Self` and you can chain it right before calling `responseJSON`. Also, I see you called `upload.responseJSON` two times, it is redundant, imho.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-validation

Comment: Larme: error: <EXPR>:3:17: error: value of type 'Any?' has no member 'class'
response.result.value.class
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~ ~~~~~

Comment: Maksym, updated to remove the dup, good point.  Upload is a bit different from the request calls I am used to using in that it has the encoding result closure, not sure where in the closure to implement .validate on the request, although that seems to be close to the proper flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `respose.result.value` looks like a dict, not an array.

Did you try casting it that way?

```
if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
   print(jsonDict)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire response will result in a dictionary.

So your `response.result.value` is a dictionary

`print(response.result)` After this line call a function  `funcJSONParsing`

```
self.funcJSONParsing(response.result.value!)
```

Write the parsing in a separate function like below.

```
func funcJSONParsing(let json:AnyObject)
    {
        if json is NSDictionary{

            let jsonResponse = json as! NSDictionary
            //Parse the below jsonResponse according to your needs
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
upload.responseJSON { (result) in
                            do {
                                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                                let model = try decoder.decode(FormResponse2.self,from: result.data!)
                                let selectDoctorForChat = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectDoctorForChat") as! SelectDoctorForChat
                                selectDoctorForChat.chatFormId = model.chat?.id
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectDoctorForChat, animated: true)
                            } catch let parsingError {
                                print("Error", parsingError)
                            }

    // MARK: - FormResponse
struct FormResponse2: Codable {
    let chat: Chat2?
}

// MARK: - Chat
struct Chat2: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let patient, doctor: String?
    let specialty: Specialty22?
    let state, createdAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, patient, doctor, specialty, state
        case createdAt = "created_at"
    }
}

// MARK: - Specialty
struct Specialty22: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
}
```